# Java - Selenium - How Can I create a good Xpath enside 2 frames

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, siebel

Im trying create a Xpath for my Siebel Script... I have the next frame:

```
//Variable
    By V_Busqueda = By.id("s_1_in2");

//Go to do click
    driver.switchTo().frame("_sweclient");
    driver.switchTo().frame("_sweviewbar");
    driver.findElement(V_Busqueda).click();
```

I can't use any tool for get the xpath because I'm working with Siebel and ActiveX and is impossible to inspect the page...

Question: How can I create a Xpath with the frame sweclient, sweviewbar and V_Busqueda (Because I dont want write three lines of code against one)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your code looks about as efficient as it can be if you are switching into 2 nested frames.

Comment: Can I combine these 2 frames and the find element and build a "xpath"?

Comment: No, because in order to see inside the first IFRAME you must switch context into it. What you have is as efficient as it gets. If you think about it, if a single XPath was able to do what you ask, you should be able to just skip the first two lines and go straight to the click but you can't because Selenium can't see the element to be clicked until you switch into the two IFRAMEs, one at a time.